# SQL-change the text of a column when a condition is meet

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am just learning DB Syntax so im sorry if this is not a relevant question.

I'm trying to change the text of a column when a condition is meet. I have tried many things but have not achieved anything.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Some PK        |     Some FK      |  someDatetime    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |     1900/01/01   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          13         |         54       |    2018/05/32    |        
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          15         |         60       |   2000/01/01     |
|------------------------------------------------------------
```

What i Need is to display this same table, but when the date is lower from 2018(I know that can be achieved with a where), the query brings this back:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Some PK        |     Some FK      |  someDatetime    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |     ----------   |
|                     |                  |  or My own string|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          13         |         54       |    2018/05/32    |        
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          15         |         60       |   ----------     |
|                     |                  | or My own string |
|------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Check out CASE statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `YEAR` function to check the date:

```
SELECT
    PK,
    FK,
    CASE WHEN YEAR(someDatetime) < 2018
         THEN 'my own string'
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, someDatetime, 120) END AS someDatetime
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that if you want to generate a text column with your message, in the case the year be earlier than 2018, then the entire `CASE` expression should generate text.  So, we can use `CONVERT` on the datetime column to generate a text version of the date.

Comment: This once the best answer, it even took into account the datetime convertion!
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

use `case when` and `Year` function for converting date to year

```
select some_PK,some_FK,
case when  Year(someDatetime)<'2018' then 'My own string' else someDatetime 
end as someDatetime    
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just do:

```
select . . . ,
       (case when someDateTime < '2018-01-01'
             then 'my own string'
             else convert(varchar(255), someDateTime)  -- might want to include a format
        end)
```

No function is needed for the date comparison, just a date comparison.